# Label on top of select moves to background when label and select are disabled in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, google-chrome

I have an input and select element with a label on top of it wrapped in a div "container1".

When I disable all the elements of container1, the label on top of the select-element moves to the back. Like the disabled label on the input-element, I want the label to stay on top. Since this happens **only in Chrome**, I tried different webkits, but nothing seemed to work.

Does anybody know a solution for this isue?

Below the code, you see a printscreen from Chrome with the problem.

You can find the code also on https://jsfiddle.net/JanRo/q4szervh/16/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <div id="container1">
        <div>
            <div>
                <label class="question" for="name">Input</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div> 
            <div>
                <label class="question" for="classnow">Select</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="classnow" name="classnow">
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                </select> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="disable()" type="button">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;     
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;  
}

#container1 > div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.question {
  top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
  font-size: small;
  background-color: white;
}

input[type=text]:disabled, select:disabled {
  outline: none !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 3px 3px 10px;
  font-size: small;
}
```

**JS**

```
function disable() {

    var nodes = document.getElementById("container1").getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      nodes[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a z-index css property to the div surrounding your labels. you should add a class name to your divs for better control. example below:

```
div.yourClassName {
 z-index: 5; /* you can set whatever number higher than 0 */
 position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <label class="question" for="classnow" style="z-index: 999;">Select</label>
```

and

```
 <div style="z-index: 1;">
            <select id="classnow" name="classnow">
                <option value="" selected></option>
            </select> 
        </div>
```

Try this it Worked for Me and If it Works Dont Forgot to UpVote